# jquery newbie onclick

Tags: jquery

If I'm in my view getting collection of images like this

```
foreach (var item in Model.Photos)
{
   <a href="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Property", new { id = item.Id })" >
      <img class="details" onclick="ImageDetails();" width="100" height="100"  src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Property", new { id = item.Id })" />
  </a>        
}
```

This will reproduce html code, I'm sure you already know but here it is:

```
<a href="/Property/GetImage/5">
  <img class="details" width="100" height="100" src="/Property/GetImage/5" onclick="ImageDetails();">
</a>
```

I tried with my Photos.js like this, just for alert message

```
function ImageDetails() {
    $(".details").click(function (event) {
        alert('details alert');     
    });
}
```

No alert, no any message in firebug?
Where did I wrong ?

Comment: Since none of the answers so far explain why it doesn't work: when you click on an image you run a function that attaches another click event to the images. In other words you have a click event handler that only creates another click event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using jQuery's `click` binder incorrectly. You don't need to call that every time the control is clicked; you call it once, usually when the page loads. It's used to bind the control's `onclick` handler for all *future* clicks.

So you have two main options:

```
//HTML:
<img class="details" onclick="ImageDetails();" width="100" ...etc.
```

Or:

```
//HTML:
<img class="details" width="100" ...etc. (no onclick attribute)

//JavaScript:
$('.details').click(ImageDetails);
```

In either case, `ImageDetails` would be set up like this:

```
function ImageDetails(event) {
   alert('details alert');  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you bind your events after the document has finished loading, or else the elements you're attempting to bind your events to won't have loaded yet.

```
$(function() {
    $(".details").click(function (event) {
        alert('details alert');     
    });
});
```

EDIT: Or you could just call `ImageDetails()` from the `onload()` function. :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. If this answer solves your problem, make it easier for others to find this solution by accepting it! =)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `onclick` attribute in your HTML and either call `ImageDetails()` once or remove it from its function and just run it after the DOM is ready.